# Equivalence between almost sure convergence and convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Here is an exercise from Resnick - Probability path (6.17):
"In a discrete probability space, convergence in probability and convergence almost sure are equivalent".

I'm not sure to have understood the meaning of the word 'equivalent' (which sounds like '=' to me). Perhaps I believe only two ways are possible to prove it:

1. Using the fact that: $X_n \to X$  i.p. iff every subsequence $X_{n_k} \to X$ a.s. ;
2. Showing that $P[(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\, i.o.]= \lim_{n\to \infty} P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=0$ (which is against Fatou's lemma indeed).

However, nor of the two seems to me to be possible, so I have no idea how to go forwards.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind that in a discrete probability space, if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability then $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]$ will be $0$ for all large $n$ (how large depends on $\epsilon$.)

Comment: Do you mean that the discrete space is monotonic?

Comment: Let's call the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Discreteness implies that the set $\{P(A): A\in\mathcal F, P(A)>0\}$ is a finite set, so $\delta:=\min\{P(A): A\in\mathcal F, P(A)>0\}>0$. Convergence in probability means that $\lim_n P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=0$, so there exists $n_0$ such that if $n>n_0$ then $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]<\delta$, which in turn means that $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=0$, by the  definition of $\delta$.

Comment: answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/333506/184903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalence of certain conditions means that they imply each other. The direction "almost sure convergence $\Rightarrow$ convergence in probability" is always true, so only the other direction has to be proven.

In a discrete probability space, almost sure convergence is pointwise convergence in all singleton sets of non-zero measure, because every subset of a discrete probability space is a countable union of singleton sets. So let $\omega$ be an element of the probability space with $P(\{\omega\})=p>0$. If $X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)$ didn't converge to $0$, then there is an $\varepsilon>0$ for which there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)\vert>\varepsilon$. What does this mean for the probability $P(\vert X-X_n\vert>\varepsilon)$, and thus for convergence in probability?

Comment: I had a really hard time understanding this answer, but I found another solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/333506/184903